# R - Criar Variável binária (dummy) valor 1 para 50% do total

Tags: r, variáveis

Bom, gostaria de uma ajuda, tenho esses dados cada coluna tem 100%,
primeiramente queria indexar do maior para o menor e posteriormente fazer o uso da variável dummy de valor igual a 1 para as espécies que somam 50%, o restante seria de valor igual a zero.

```
           Nome      Dens      Freq       Dom
1       Abarema  9.090909 46.153846 29.411765
2         Abuta 13.636364 11.538462 23.529412
3     Agonandra 18.181818  7.692308 11.764706
4        Aiouea 22.727273 15.384615 29.411765
5 Alchorneopsis 36.363636 19.230769  5.882353
```

Resultado:

```
           Nome      Dens      Freq       Dom v1 v2 v3
1       Abarema  9.090909 46.153846 29.411765  0  1  1
2         Abuta 13.636364 11.538462 23.529412  0  0  0
3     Agonandra 18.181818  7.692308 11.764706  0  0  0
4        Aiouea 22.727273 15.384615 29.411765  1  0  1
5 Alchorneopsis 36.363636 19.230769  5.882353  1  1  0
```

Se puderem me ajudar, fico grato.

Comment: Olá André, bem vindo ao StackOverflow PT, primeiramente gostaria de te pedir uma explicação mais detalhada do seu problema, porque está um pouco confuso e assim difícil de entender. Segundo seria bastante legal se pudesse colocar um pouco do que você conseguiu fazer até agora, pois assim a comunidade consegue ver que é um problema que está se empenhando para resolver, e que não se trata de um caso em que você esta perguntando algo sem ao menos ter tentado.

Comment: De um `dput` nos seus dados, pois fica mais fácil de trabalhar no código com a mesma base de dados que você possui.

Comment: Como é que calcula *"as espécies que somam 50%"*? Somando os valores a partir do maior até chegar aos 50%? No seu exemplo é isso que parece ter feito.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas orientações, foi a primeira postagem que realizei. O exemplo abaixo funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creio que o seguinte código resolve o problema da pergunta.

Primeiro defino uma função que processa as colunas de classe `numeric` e cria cada *dummy*. Faz isso somando os valores a partir do maior até chegar ou ultrapassar os 50%. Esses valores serão codificados como `1L` (classe `integer`) e os outros como `0L`.

```
dummyFun <- function(x){
  n <- NROW(x)
  inx <- order(x, decreasing = TRUE)
  d <- which(cumsum(x[inx]) >= 50)[1]
  d <- c(rep(1L, d), rep(0L, n - d))[order(inx)]
  d
}

num <- sapply(dados, is.numeric)

dum <- sapply(dados[num], dummyFun)
colnames(dum) <- paste0("v", seq_len(ncol(dum)))
Resultado <- cbind(dados, dum)
rm(dum, num)    # Limpeza final

Resultado
#           Nome      Dens      Freq       Dom v1 v2 v3
#1       Abarema  9.090909 46.153846 29.411765  0  1  1
#2         Abuta 13.636364 11.538462 23.529412  0  0  0
#3     Agonandra 18.181818  7.692308 11.764706  0  0  0
#4        Aiouea 22.727273 15.384615 29.411765  1  0  1
#5 Alchorneopsis 36.363636 19.230769  5.882353  1  1  0
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que estava precisando. Obrigado pela ajuda e desculpem a confusão nos dados da pergunta.